# Problem with typing special characters in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, editor

After updating PyCharm to 2019.1 version I can't type those language specific characters: "ąężźćśół". Problem appears only in editor - In terminal or outside the program I can write them normally. However problem is shared between any file type inside editor like *.txt

IdeaVim is not installed. I'm using Consolas font (it was working previously, I haven't changed it.) and copy-paste those characters works good. Also encoding is set to utf-8 (But I also tried Windows-default - still no results). Only plugin I use is Bash Support.

So what could cause the problem and what can I do to type them like before?

Comment: Sounds similar to the known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/idea-209426 Try the workaround in the description.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! I was looking for answer for some time and haven't found this one, solved problem immediately.